# Honeybadger on localhost with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

I've set up Honeybadger almost a year ago and so far it works like a charm registering errors on my production and staging environments.

Then I decided to make a custom error behavior in controller. I am using the code similar to:

```
     begin
      params = {
        :id => 1,
        :class => MyClass,
        :foo => "bar"
      }
      my_unpredicable_method(*params)
    rescue => e
      Honeybadger.notify(
        :error_class   => "Special Error",
        :error_message => "Special Error: #{e.message}",
        :parameters    => params
      )
    end
```

which is described [here](http://docs.honeybadger.io/article/41-manually-sending-exceptions-and-events).

I was going to test in local environmet to tune error messages, passing params, etc.
But the problem is when I receive the error (I am sure that I receive it, tested with debugger) nothing is sent to honeybadger website. Meanwhile, `rake honeybadger:test` works fine and sends the testing error messages to the server from localhost. Also, this custom notification works if I push it to testing environment on Heroku.

The question is:

**What should I do to send this custom error to honeybadger from localhost?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. We need to add the following option to honeybadger initializer:

```
config.development_environments = %w(test)
```

This option is the list of environments in which notifications should not be sent and by default `development` in the list. See detailed explanation of the configuring option [here](http://docs.honeybadger.io/article/133-development-configuration-options).

Answer (score 0):

Please add following configuration in config/honeybadger.yml

```
development:
  report_data: true
```

Please read https://github.com/honeybadger-io/honeybadger-ruby#configuration-options